# clean a char buffer in c

Tags: c, buffer

I have the next situation I have a loop for read a data from a gprs by serial port and this data is storage in a char buffer named c but before I need clean the buffer to print only the repond from my gprs and not the command previously sent.
my code:

```
    while(ciclo)
    {
        c=data[i];
        i++;
        if(c != '\0')
        {
           write(tty_fd,&c,1);    
        }
        else
        {
            ciclo = false;
        }

    }
    ciclo = true;
    //int veces = 0;
    //here I need clean c var
    while(ciclo)
    {
        nanosleep((struct timespec[]){{0, INTERVAL_MS}}, NULL);
        //veces++;
        //printf("durmio 0,5 por %i vez \n",veces);
        fflush(&c);
        if(read(tty_fd,&c,1)>0)
        {   
            write(STDOUT_FILENO,&c,1);
            //append(respuesta,c);
            //printf("respuesta %s",respuesta);
        } 
        else
        {
            ciclo = false;
        }
    }
```

I tried with fflush and fpurge but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: You don't need to clean the buffer before reading into it. `read()` will overwrite whatever is there.

Comment: The argument to `fflush` should be a stream like `stdout`, not a buffer address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`c` is a `char` so you don't necessarily need to clean it especially if you are then going to overwrite it with `read`.

```
if(read(tty_fd,&c,1)>0)
```

This line prevents your code from executing the `write` function unless `read` has returned a value greater than 0. Which means that `c` has been overwrited.

Comment: so why print "at \r ok" in the stout instead "ok" than is the repond of my gprs,("at \r") is the string sent for my from to gprs.

Comment: ok, you was right, and I found the error, this was in the gprs module configuration, it sent me a echo and this confused me. thanks a lot